# How to print dictionary of lists in especific order?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list from a previous step.

```
lst = [
        ['A', 1], ['B', 0], ['C', 2], ['D', 7], 
                                      ['D', 2], ['E', 1], 
                            ['C', 0], ['D', 3],          ['F', 8], 
        ['A', 1], ['B', 0], ['C', 4], ['D', 5],                   ['H', 9]
    ]
```

and I'd like to tabulate it in this way. In the output, A and B fields appear only once, then I'd like to fill them down as shown in green.

**Desired output**

[image]

currently this is my code, with which I'm relating the fields with corresponding values. Now I don't know how to continue
in order to print in desired order, since the resulting dictionary has lists of different size. I hope make sense.

```
columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','H']

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in lst:
    d[k].append(v)

>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': [1, 1], 'B': [0, 0], 'C': [2, 0, 4], 'D': [7, 2, 3, 5], 'E': [1], 'F': [8], 'H': [9]})
```

Comment: @TomServo Since 3.7, dictionaries are guaranteed to preserve insertion order; sets still have no guaranteed order. OP, are you looking for some kind of table as output as you showed, or just modifying the dict so that the values of the lists d['A'] and d['B'] are repeated to match the longest list in the dictionary?

Comment: I'm trying to get a output table in the format I show in image. Thanks

Comment: @PCM not needed to make it using dictionary, is the way I currently have to get a kind of order. My goal actually is to get a table like I show in image

Comment: Actually, python does not format output in such a manner, but if you want to do that, then make a string inside which the output is formatted in desired way..

Comment: What is the type of such a table? Are you looking for suggestions on Python libraries that support making tables (like Pandas), or asking about how to modify data inside standard Python dictionaries and defaultdicts?

Comment: "A and B fields appear only once": do you mean that they appear more than once but with the same value? Because E, F and H are the ones that appear only once.

Comment: @jferard you can see like blocks that begin with list [A,x] then comes [B,x] and could come optional [C,x], ...[H,x]. the lists that contain A or B appears once in that "block" then the lists that contain C to H could repeat one or more times. Then the cicle repeats coming with a new "block" that begins with lists containing [A,x] and [B,x]. Due to that I'd like to "fill down"  A and B in output since they appear only once in each "block"

Comment: @kcsquared It could be using python or any way to modify the data accordinly to get the output table I show in image. Could be without the need to use dictionary, but manipulating the input list. I used dictionary as a way to try to relationate the fields with the values.

Comment: @GerCas If I understand, A and B are different from other cols because they signal the beginning of a block. It's a coincidence if the A and B values on the fourth row are the same as the ones on the first row. They could have different values. If there was a fifth, sixth,... row without A and B values, then you would like to copy the ones of the fourth row.

Comment: @GerCas How do you known that `['D', 7]` is on the first row and not on the second? Would it be different if there was a newline before `['D', 7]`? Your `lst` is just a formatted list of `[col_name, value]` but this formatting has no meaning for Python.

Comment: @jferard Hi, I've asked a question with more details in this thread if you have chance to take a look. Basically are like blocks. Actually I'm getting a list that is far from output I want. Thanks again. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69324422/5691558