# Read text file to store data in a nested list

Tags: python, list, parsing

I have the following input file with the format as below.

```
SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT
SOME TEXT
RETCODE = 0

                        A = 1
                        B = 5
                        C = 3

                        D = 0
                        E = 0

                        D = 4
                        E = 1
                        G = 1


blah blah


---    ENDBLOCK

SOME TEXT
RETCODE = 0
                        A = 3
                        B = 2
                        C = 8
                        D = 6
                        E = 9
                        F = 3



blah blah

blah blah

---    ENDBLOCK

SOME TEXT
RETCODE = 0
                        A = 7
                        B = 2
                        C = 2
                        D = 9
                        E = 0

                        D = 1
                        E = 4

                        D = 7
                        E = 0
                        F = 1

                        D = 1
                        G = 8


blah blah

blah blah

---    ENDBLOCK
```

It shows data in blocks. Each block begins with `A= some value` and the block ends with
a line saying `---    ENDBLOCK`. Each block has `sub block` and each sub block begins after a blank line.

For example, for first block the first sub block A=1, B=5, C=3, second sub block is D=0, E=0 and 3rd sub block is D=4, E=1, G=1.

My goal is kind of complex and is to get a list showing the values for A to G for each sub block. If there is no value, show empty. Desired output below.

```
[
    [
        [1,5,3,,,,],[,,,0,0,,],[,,,4,1,,1]
    ],
    [
        [3,2,8,6,9,3,]
    ],
    [
        [7,2,2,9,0,,],[,,,1,4,,],[,,,7,0,1,],[,,,1,,,8]
    ]
]
```

My current code is reading the file and storing the data at some level but still I'm far from the desired output. Thanks for any help.

```
f=open("file.txt","r").read().split("ENDBLOCK")
rows = []
for line in f:
    for subline in line.split("\n\n"):
        if " = " in subline and not "RETCODE" in subline:
            rows.append(subline.replace(" ","").split())

>>> rows
[
    ['A=1', 'B=5', 'C=3'], ['D=0', 'E=0'], ['D=4', 'E=1', 'G=1'], 
    ['D=1', 'E=4'], ['D=7', 'E=0', 'F=1'], ['D=1', 'G=8']
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import re

BLOCK_END = "---    ENDBLOCK"
LETTER_TO_VALUE_REGEX = re.compile(r"\s+(?P<letter>[A-G]) = (?P<number>\d*)")
LETTERS = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
SUB_BLOCK_END = "\n\n"


top_list = []
for block in text.split(BLOCK_END):
    if not block:
        continue
    sub_list = []
    for sub_block in block.split(SUB_BLOCK_END):
        if not sub_block:
            continue
        letters_to_numbers_dict = {}
        for line in sub_block.split("\n"):
            match = LETTER_TO_VALUE_REGEX.match(line)
            if match:
                letters_to_numbers_dict[match["letter"]] = int(match["number"])
        inner_list = []
        for letter in LETTERS:
            inner_list.append(letters_to_numbers_dict.get(letter, ""))
        if set(inner_list) not in [{""}]:
                sub_list.append(inner_list) 
    top_list.append(sub_list)
```

and then "top_list" is your desired list

Comment: I tried again and it works. Thanks so much for the help. Only if possible, how would change your code if instead of letters are words? The actual file contains words instead of letters and numbers or letter in values.

Comment: Are there specific word or can it be any set of words? If it's specific words I would change the list of letters to the words you might have and in the regex use \w+ instead of [A-G] and \d*. Also you can change names to make it clearer (change "letters" to "words" etc.

Comment: Would be specific set of words, let say,`FRUITS, MIXED, ORANGE, APPLE, GRAPE, MANGO, LEMON` and instead of a number could be `GRAPE = TRUE`, `APPLE = ENOUGH`, `MIXED=34892`.

Comment: So changing to this should work (don't forget to remove the int casting of the value): LETTER_TO_VALUE_REGEX = re.compile(r"\s+(?P<letter>\w+) = (?P<number>\w+)")
LETTERS = ["FRUITS", "MIXED", "ORANGE", "APPLE", "GRAPE", "MANGO", "LEMON"]